# try catch final is not catching exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, exception, try-catch

While on return to my app from getting phone number from address book, if by mistake i fetch some address or any thing except for phone number, the code in the try catch final gives the following but doesn't catch it, any idea is appreciated in advance:

```
  *** -[CFDictionary length]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a4db70
```

Code:

```
strContact = (NSString *)phone; CFRelease(phone);
// NSLog(@"%@", strContact);
CFRelease(multi);
name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z]" options:0 error:NULL] autorelease];
// Assuming you have some NSString myString.
NSUInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:strContact options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strContact length])];
```

Comment: please put some **code** in the question

Comment: Is another catch block catching it first, perhaps?

Comment: strContact = (NSString *)phone;
            CFRelease(phone); 
   // NSLog(@"%@", strContact);
    CFRelease(multi); 
    
    name = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty); 
    
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [[[NSRegularExpression alloc]
                                   initWithPattern:@"[a-zA-Z]" options:0 error:NULL] autorelease];
    
    // Assuming you have some NSString `myString`.
    NSUInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:strContact options:0
                                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [strContact length])];

Comment: i am getting error in NSMakeRange

Comment: Where are the try/catch blocks in your code?

Comment: code above is inside try catch @FirozeLafeer

Comment: Stop **describing** your code.  Just **show** us your code.  **All** of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I understand your question now. It just took me a while.

So, I'm assuming you have Zombie Objects enabled (NSZombieEnabled) and you're wondering why you can't catch this error --sending a message to a zombie-- with a @try/@catch structure.

The short answer is NSZombies don't throw an Objective-C exception (one that you can catch this way). There wouldn't really be a point to that, since you wouldn't actually ship an app with NSZombieEnabled anyway. This is meant to be a debugging tool that you use at the debugger or within Instruments.

In your actual app, when you turn off NSZombie's, there still wouldn't be an exception to catch for this, since you would just get an EXE_BAD_ACCESS, which is a UNIX signal (not this type of an exception at this level).

The last point is that Objective-C exceptions (the type that you **can** @try/@catch) are not recommended for errors that you expect to be able to recover from. Or in other words, this is meant for fatal errors only, where you might do some cleanup and then allow your app to still crash.

The right way to do what you're trying to do is to actually test for different types or different values that you might except to get and then handle each case appropriately. You can do this using normal if/else conditionals or something of that sort. You can test values for `nil` if you need to and you can see if an object is of a particular class by using `[someObj isKindOfClass:[MyExpectedClass class]]`

I hope I understood the question correctly?

Comment: thanks for your help, you got me, last question, i am working with uncaught exception handling, i don't know how would it work, would you kindly tell me that the issue is that its not any type of exception. what would i call it,

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. Can you give me an example?

Comment: i mean i am adding implementation of uncaught exception handling to my project where necessary          http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html        secondly i want to ask what is difference between zombie and exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that you are releasing `phone` after assigning it to `strContact`, and then using `strContact`.  The string object is probably getting deallocated when you release `phone`, so the pointer in `strContact` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `phone` is a string? Looks like you're storing that object in a NSString* pointer 'strContact' that is probably not a string, hence the 'CFDictionary' in the error messages.

Looks like you have two problems to fix:

1. Getting the object of the right type.
2. Ensuring that you don't release objects before you need to. Try put the CFRelease after you've finished using the object!

Comment: yes i got it i just want to know why this exception is not caught in try catch final. I put a check for phonenumberproperty only which is working fine now, I actually want to use exception handling in future unexpected exception