# KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash-reports

I got this Crash often Can you please help me to find out solution

```
Incident Identifier: BC2870F3-4119-462B-9B2E-2236E403E7C2
CrashReporter Key:   7d9cc50413d82f64739259a761dbb92e755b623d
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         project name [16361]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/7190A4F4-3A65-4663-9BEC-389AAFFE9851/project name.app/project name
Identifier:      project name
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-06-29 18:23:33.732 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x3002bd4f
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x362fdf78 0x362fa000 + 16248
1   CoreFoundation                  0x34e3ed2e 0x34e23000 + 113966
2   CFNetwork                       0x338ab190 0x338a9000 + 8592
3   CFNetwork                       0x338ab00a 0x338a9000 + 8202
4   CFNetwork                       0x338aafa2 0x338a9000 + 8098
5   Foundation                      0x30cfe15e 0x30cee000 + 65886
6   Foundation                      0x30cfe090 0x30cee000 + 65680
7   Foundation                      0x30cfe04e 0x30cee000 + 65614
8   project name                    0x00015c6c 0x1000 + 85100
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x30f01c52 0x30f01000 + 3154
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x30f0ce8a 0x30f01000 + 48778
11  CoreFoundation                  0x34eaf2a6 0x34e23000 + 574118
12  CoreFoundation                  0x34e3249e 0x34e23000 + 62622
13  CoreFoundation                  0x34e32366 0x34e23000 + 62310
14  GraphicsServices                0x3612e432 0x3612a000 + 17458
15  UIKit                           0x31f28e76 0x31ef7000 + 204406
16  project name                    0x0005ac10 0x1000 + 367632
17  project name                    0x00002804 0x1000 + 6148
```

above crash report i got from organizer, here it shows the KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS. I can't understand about this. Please Help me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS type of code which relates to accessing deallocated memory. In order to find this you need to enable NSZombie objects. Press Option + Command + R and select the "Diagnostics" tab. Finally, click "Enable Zombie Objects". This should make the compiler stop on the line of code that is causing this crash.

Most likely you have released an object and then tried to access it afterwards.

Comment: hi @jamie i'm getting "select error receiving message: Invalid argument warning" and "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" pointing "udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];" can you please give me the solution

Comment: I facing same issue but in production. I tried in development no recreate. Any suggestion whats wrong?

Comment: Yeah I've got this same crash but it only happens when the app is running for 3-4 hours. Debugging hell.